# Drupal migration issue Blocks not showing

Tags: linux, drupal, ubuntu, migration, block

I have drupal in one linux machine (Fedora). now i want to host into another linux machine (Ubuntu). I copied database and Drupal site into new machine. But now problem is my custom theme is not showing for Blocks in admin section. and also Regions not showing in admin side which has created inmy customtheme.info file. I dont know the solution. Please rectify my problem

Comment: Did you migrate the /site/all folder? (or at least copy the relevant files from it)?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to clear Drupal blocks cache:

```
drush cc block
```

In regards to regions - make sure your theme is picked up and set as active/default. Clearing theme registry may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this check list and see:

1) Make sure your theme name is unique and is not similar to any module name. In the past this has caused problems for me.
2) Try installing your theme in a new installation and see it it works. If it does then we know the problem is with your current instance.
3) Did you mix up drupal 6 and drupal 7 ?
This could be a compatibility issue.
4) "Drush cc all" is clears all the cache. However try to use firefox and remove the browser cache too. This could be another reason.

Still not solved ?

paste your .info file here and if possible give a link to your theme for review.